# View in Access Database 2007

Tags: ms-access

```
PARAMETERS [prmAuto] Long;
CREATE VIEW view (IndexItemCaption) AS
SELECT IndexItemCaption FROM IndexItems WHERE Auto = prmAuto;
```

This create view doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain yourself. What do you mean by "doesn't work for me"? Do you get an error message? Does the view work but yields the wrong results?

Comment: ms-access returns "invalid sql statement" when i try to execute it.

Comment: have you tried changing the name of the view from "view" to maybe something else like "myview" ? "view" is a keyword so that may be the problem!!

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to show that Access returns that error message. Your question is unclear without that.

Answer (score 1):

See Microsoft's SQL Reference for the [CREATE VIEW Statement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-view-statement-HA001231443.aspx)  Under the Remarks heading, it says:

*The SELECT statement that defines the view cannot contain any parameters.*

Use DAO to create your query instead.  See [Database.CreateQueryDef Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243014%28office.12%29.aspx)

And, as @InSane suggested, don't use "view" as the name of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a view in Access with a parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895(office.12).aspx). Furthermore, the create view statement will not run in the query design window unless you set SQL server compatible Syntax (ANSI 92).

Is VBA to create a query (view) an option form you?

```
s = "PARAMETERS [prmAuto] Long; " _
& "SELECT IndexItemCaption FROM IndexItems WHERE Auto = prmAuto;"

CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "IndexItemCaption", s
```